# Javascript Variable with Highest Number

Tags: javascript

How do I select the variable associated with the highest number? If I have p1 =1 , p2=4 and p3=3, how can I make the program choose the highest one(in this case p2?)

Comment: You need to scope them...

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far

Comment: You asked how the program can choose a given variable (which for me makes little sense), but I reckon you simply want the **value** instead: `consr foo = Math.max(p1, p2, p3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* apply a scope to the parameters, so that you reduce the number of variables you need to scan for.

```js
let myScope = {};

myScope.p1 = 1;
myScope.p2 = 4;
myScope.p3 = 3;

console.log(getHighest(myScope)); // 4

function getHighest(scope) {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, Object.values(scope));
}
```

**Note:** A better alternative would be to have a variable called `p` to store the values e.g.

```js
var p = [ 1, 4, 3 ];
var max = Math.max.apply(Max, p);
```

---

**NOT ADVISED:** You could also access them from the window, but this is tricker...

```js
var p1 = 1;
var p2 = 4;
var p3 = 3;

console.log(getHighest(window, /^p\d$/)); // 4

function getHighest(scope, pattern) {
  return Math.max.apply(
    Math,
    Object.keys(scope)
      .filter(k => k.match(pattern))
      .map(k => scope[k])
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary.

Comment: In case anyone reading this asks "why not just `Math.max(p1, p2, p3)`", this approach does not require you to manually key in your keys everytime you add values to the scope. This can also be done using Array instead of object literal.

Comment: @YongQuan indeed, but look at the word **need**: *"You need to apply a scope to the parameters..."*. And also a comment in the question, by the same answerer: *"You need to scope them"*. It's **not** necessary.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I agree. You don't *need* to do this if your context doesn't require dynamically adding values.

Comment: This answers the OPs question, but it's really doing them a disservice by not explaining that their general structure is bad. If you have a bunch a variables with name like `p1`, `p2`... those almost certainly belong in a array name `p` accessed with `p[0]`, `p[1]`... To use a regex to look for a variable in the window object only to find the max from a bunch of like-named variables is such a bad code smell I can taste it. It's really not helpful to anyone to offer this as an answer.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I went ahead and updated/annotated the response. Thanks.